# Avoid typing out all go files in the main package when "Go run"-ng

Tags: go

When you have multiple .go files in a `main` package, i need to list them all out when doing a `go run`.

So when i have `main.go`, `a.go`, `b.go` and they all belong to the main package, i need to type `go run main.go a.go b.go` in order to use functions and structs inside the other 2 go files. The `go build` command however, is smart enough to link all files together automatically.

Have i misunderstood something about Go, or is this normal (listing out all the files in the `main` package when doing a `go run`)?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: you need to list them all out. You can do this with shell tricks, if you're desperate. I usually just write a shell script to `go build` and then run the resulting executable, after it gets too annoying.

```
# this works unless you have _test.go files
go run *.go

# if you really want to... enable extended glob
shopt -s extglob
# so you can do something like this (matches all .go except *_test.go files)
go run !(*_test).go
```

Check out this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/EOi0VAQNA4c

Answer (score 2):

If your source is in $GOPATH/src
as in

```
$GOPATH/src/somedir/main.go
$GOPATH/src/somedir/a.go
$GOPATH/src/somedir/b.go
```

doing "go install somedir" will compile and install the somedir binary in to $GOPATH/bin

no need to list out the files individually

"go install" finds all the files on it's own.

My common work cycle with go is (from my bash prompt):
$ clear; go install myproj && $GOPATH/bin/myproj

which, clears the screen, builds and installs "myproj" and then runs it

so, after I change code, I just hit Ctrl-C, Up arrow, and enter.

Entire cycle time is ~1 second (for small to start stuff)

Comment: he's asking about `go run`, though.

Comment: good point, I just made a (bad) assumption that he wasn't aware of how to make runnable binaries in go (which I struggled with originally when learning go)

Comment: yeah, I usually write a script called run.sh that does something similar to yours; usually I use `go build` for a local build instead of `go install`.