# Why the functions defined in other "main" packages are not recognised?

Tags: go

I have to files main.go and main2.go . In main.go I have the main() function defined along with a call somefunc() which is in main2.go. The issue is that when I run go run main.go it says that somefunc() is undefined. Basically it doesn't scan the other main functions from package. However if I declare this somefunc() in main.go it works but when I run go test it says the function is redeclared.

Question: Is there any way that I can tell to `go run` to behave like go test and compile/run all the files from the package(in this case both main.go and main1.go)  not just main.go?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid typing out all go files in the main package when "Go run"-ng](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916376/avoid-typing-out-all-go-files-in-the-main-package-when-go-run-ng)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must include all the files as argument of the `go run`.

```
go run main1.go main.go
```

or

```
go *.go
```

Unless there are test files in the same folder.

Comment: Although `go build && ./progname` is *far* preferable, if there are test files and/or files with build constraints and you *really really* want to use `go run` you could do (or make an alias for): ``go run `go list -f '{{join .GoFiles " "}}'` `` (assuming no spaces or "strange" characters in the filenames).