# Difference between go run ./path/dir and go run path/dir

Tags: go

Note: This is not asking [Why the functions defined in other "main" packages are not recognised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571477/why-the-functions-defined-in-other-main-packages-are-not-recognised).

I've got a project with the following structure:

*go/src/github.com/me/project/cmd/web/main.go*

```
# main.go
package main

import(
  "github.com/me/myproject/internal/myproject"
)

void main() {
  // ...
}
```

*go/src/github.com/me/project/cmd/web/handlers.go*

```
# handlers.go
package main

void someFunc() {
  // ...
}
```

And I compile and run successfully with:

```
go run ./cmd/web
```

I can also run successfully with `go run cmd/web/*.go`

However, when I try to run with `go run cmd/web`, why does compilation fail with the output:

```
package cmd/web: package cmd/web is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/cmd/web)
```

Why does `./cmd/web` work, but `cmd/web` does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `./cmd/web`, you refer to the correct directory in your current directory tree.

`cmd/web` however refers to a package living where the stdlib packages are. If you try to run this example

```
go run net/http
```

It will tell you that it can't run it because its not a `main` package. It has found the stdlib `net/http` package with that name; but since `cmd/web` doesn't exist it doesn't work